# Mensaje de validación de formulario wordpress repetido

Tags: wordpress

[image: formulario]

Hice este formulario con `WordPress` el `plugin contac form 7` y el mensaje de envío me sale duplicado, ya investigue pero no encontré nada respecto a esto.
Gracias.

Comment: y el código? Sin código difícilmente podemos adivinar porqué sale dos veces.
Necesitariamos el código del formulario y el código de la página en la cual incrustas el formulario (HTML y plantilla utilizada)
Un saludo

Comment: Verifica si estás cargando más de una instancia de jQuery!!